# Unable to compile UWP Class library after upgrading reference project to .Net Standard 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, visual-studio-2017, .net-standard

Previously I was having a class library targeting .Net Standard 1.4, but I upgraded it to .Net Standard 2.0 and also updated UWP class library to target SDK 16299 but on compiling the UWP Class library project it is giving below error:

> The type 'DateTime' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.

Seems like I am missing something, but can't actually figure out what it is, also tried modifying .csproject by adding below line but that also didn't worked.

```
 <ItemGroup> <Reference Include="netstandard" /> </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: min/target version must be both Build 16299. also add this to the csproj: **<PackageReference Include="NETStandard.Library">
      <Version>2.0.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>**

Comment: Does the above comment works in your side?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks, I tried your suggestion but that didn't worked. What I tried is installing Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime.CoreCLR package and upgrading Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform to latest version did worked.

Comment: post your steps as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating four couple of days, finally I was able to build the solution. 
Below are the steps that I followed to make it work:

1> Installed `Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime.CoreCLR` from [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime.CoreCLR/)

2> Upgrade to the latest version of `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform`

Still I am not sure why I need CoreCLR library, would appreciate if anyone have explanation for it. Right now am okay as far as my project is building.

Comment: Did you add anything else in the .csproj file?

Comment: @MarceloFilho No. I didn't add anything else to the .csproj file.